# Expression tree with linq expressions

Tags: c#, linq

I have been playing with expression trees this week and I am wondering why this expression produces error when ran.

```
var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Nullable<DateTime>));

var ex = Expression.Lambda<Func<DateTime?, bool>>(
   (Expression<Func<DateTime?, bool>>) (x => x.HasValue), pe);
```

The idea behind this is to write expression trees with a mix of expression tree api and linq expressions. It would make things easier to write for example instead of calling `Expression.Property(...,..)` I would just have `x => x.Prop`, right?

In my example instead of this `Expression.Property(..hasvalue..)` I would have this: `x.HasValue`. It would save me time on writing and it would look shorter, right?

The question is, is this possible?

I guess I might be missing something about

```
Expression<Func<DateTime?, bool>> foo = x => x.HasValue (this works)
```

and

```
Func<DateTime?, bool> bar = x => x.HasValue (this works too)
```

What is happening behind those two? Are they the same?

Can linq expression be mixed with standard expression tree api???

Please enlighten me on this, I feel lost. :)

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question.  Your two quotations

```
Expression<Func<DateTime?, bool>> foo = x => x.HasValue
```

and

```
Func<DateTime?, bool> bar = x => x.HasValue
```

are examples of *homoiconicity*: the same symbol (in your case x => x.HasValue) stands for two very different objects.  In the first case, it indicates an expression tree; in the second, a function.  The former can be compiled down to the latter, but they are different types with different purposes.  It is the declaration in your case that tells the compiler which version to go for.  In the absence of this context, the compiler cannot read your mind and decides to bail out instead.  That's why this won't compile:

```
var bat = x => x.HasValue;
```

And that is why your statement won't compile.

Homoiconicity is what makes `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` look so similar.  When you invoke

```
var filteredCollection = myCollection.Where(e => e.IsActive);
```

you are actually calling methods with a different signature depending on the type of `filteredCollection` (It's `Func<MyClass, bool>` for `IEnumerable` and `Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>` for `IQueryable`).

Regarding your specific situation, you can't achieve what you want to do directly, but if you write a sneaky extension method:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> Lambda<T, TProperty>(this ParameterExpression pe, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProperty>>(property, pe);
    }
}
```

then you can do this:

```
var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DateTime?));
var ex = pe.Lambda<DateTime?, bool>(x => x.HasValue);
```

Comment: Good answer, though the statement as to why `var bat = x => x.HasValue;` won't compile could be misread given the context.  To elaborate, the problem is not just that the lambda could be interpreted as an `Expression<>` or a delegate, but rather that delegates are not structural types in C#/.NET.  As opposed to most functional languages (F#, Scala, etc.) in which such a function would be typed as "a function accepting a `DateTime?` and evaluating to `bool`", in C# such a lambda has to be bound to a specific, named delegate type, of which there could be any number with identical signatures.

Comment: The question whether I may mix lambda and expression trees is still not answered. If yes how may I mix them. Do I need to convert from one to another? Can you post an example. Why cant I place Expression<Func<DateTime?, bool>> in expression tree? Its an expression. It is.

Comment: The short answer is no, but there are workarounds if you're happy to write sneaky little extension methods.